# Направление гравитации Particle System [Unity, C#]

Tags: c#, unity3d

Как задать направление гравитации по оси Z для частиц Particle System в Unity используя С#. Желательно чтобы ось Z синхронизировалась с осью Z другого объекта. Пример - ракета - нужно чтобы направление частиц огня синхронизировалось с направлением ракеты.

Answer (score 0):

Измените rotation объекта с партиклами, на rotation "ракеты". Можно создать компонент с частицами, на самом объекте двигателя - ракеты

Comment: Если бы все было так просто... Particle System работает относительно земли, как бы его не вертеть.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ixx7z1 http://prntscr.com/ixx8ba . Вполне себе ротейтится на по всем осям

Comment: Посмотрите, что бы у вас был выбран здесь локал http://prntscr.com/ixxai8